# How to find tasks of a certain type through all projects?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-build Java project being built with Gradle.

To hide Illegal reflective access warnings I want to find JavaExec and Test tasks within several projects and provide the required JVM arguments. Rather than add these to each project, I want to apply this to all projects in the root build.gradle.

How do I find certain tasks of a certain type throughout all projects?

My intial attempt uses [withType](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskCollection.html#withType-java.lang.Class-) however I want to remove the duplication of repeating this for the JavaExec and Test task types. See below:

**Attempt #1**

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
       it.jvmArgs "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
    }

    project.tasks.withType(Test) {
        it.jvmArgs "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
    }
  }
}

subprojects {
  version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
afterEvaluate {
    [JavaExec, Test].each {
        project.tasks.withType(it) {
            it.jvmArgs "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you don't mind could explain a bit more how it works? For instance, in Gradle how are you able to reference the task types JavaExec and Type almost like enums?

Comment: `[JavaExec, Test]` is a Groovy list of `Class` on which an iteration is made.
For instance, `[String, Integer].each { println it }` will display :
`class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer`

Comment: So guessing in Groovy the .class part can be dropped? 

How might one achieve the same through creating an annoymous implementation of the Spec interface? (via using tasks.matching in the TaskCollection class)

Not that I am recommending using it over your approach but I would like to further understand how Groovy code integrates with the build file. I find it difficult to understand how one tranlates between the TaskCollection#matching API to what is required in the build file.

Comment: Ah I think I got what I was doing wrong! This is Just For Fun mind:

It was my lack of Groovy knowledge. I was referencing JavaExec.class.

Comment: Just adding a Gist here for reference:
https://gist.github.com/binarycreations/e87e1a322f37d1f7cbdee57a3123a6c0